# Qt - QPixmap converts png to gray scale?

Tags: c++, qt, png

In Qt I used the following method to load images and set them as the background of QLabels:

```
QPixmap *pixmap= new QPixmap("home\\Images\\circle.png");
ui->cell11_Image->setPixmap(*pixmap);
ui->cell11_Image->setMask(pixmap->mask());
ui->cell11_Image->show();

delete(pixmap);
```

With the following result

[image]

The thing is: the images are in grayscale. However, here is one of the images

[image]

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: do you have any stylesheet in your form?

Comment: Why is this call `ui->cell11_Image->setMask(pixmap->mask());` needed?

Comment: @vahancho I do. I have two stylesheets. I removed them but it didn't change the described behaviour.
Regarding the setMask line: I wanted that only the area covered by the image to be shown. Removing that line does not change the previous behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your label or one of parent widget is disable. Try to enable and check.

Comment: (sigh) Embarrassingly for me, you are right. The QLabels were disabled. Thank you for your answer